# When implementing a JSONRPC 2.0 server, is it required to support both named, and positional arguments?

Tags: json-rpc

According the spec here: http://groups.google.com/group/json-rpc/web/json-rpc-2-0

more specifically, this section:

> If present, parameters for the rpc
>   call MUST be provided as a Structured
>   value. Either by-position through an
>   Array or by-name through an Object.

To me it seems obvious that both styles must be supported, however I've filed a bug report and another developer feels that it's up the developers to decide which method to support, and that the spec doesn't require both.

I can't find an official answer, other than what I quoted above, which the other developer doesn't interpret the same way I do.

So, what is the general consensus?

Answer (score 3):

I agree fully, it is clearly outlined in the above documentation. The word "must" in 4.2 sentence one requires a "structured value". The "structured value" is later defined by the second sentence. To ignore one of the options would be to change the definition of "structured value" which is a violation of JSON-RPC 2.0 Specification

1. If present, parameters for the rpc call MUST be provided as a Structured value.
2. Either by-position through an Array or by-name through an Object.

Answer (score 1):

Joining your side, and I did not think this could be controversial.

Comment: another developer chimed in against me too, the decision has been made to implement half of the spec. http://trac.xbmc.org/ticket/10095